# Should I replace GA snippet with GTM snippet?

Tags: google-analytics

Similar questions on this topic exists but they all seem a bit out of date.

I'm using Google Analytics snippet on my website and it works really well. However, I would like to track individual elements and therefore I am planning on installed Google Tag Manger to help me.

My question is, should I replace the GA snippet with the GTM snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to you. You can still trigger events using analytics.js or even gtag.js. Just need a little javascript.

GTM makes it easier to track elements based on attributes, css selectors, etc.

Answer (score 1):

We moved from GA to GTM a while ago at my place of employment. As your website grows and you add more tags to it, GTM makes life much easier in terms of adding, testing and deploying. Would highly recommend moving to GTM.

For Google Analytics specifically, you get a lot more flexibility in terms of custom events, attributes etc as mentioned by xtothel above.

Comment: Thanks for the input. So you removed the GA snippet and added GTM snippet and now all your tracking is done through GTM?

Comment: @Boosted_d16 if you have GTM on the page already, I would say 99.9% of the time you won't need to have the GA snippet. the other 0.1% is if there are very custom implementations with the GA snippet that you just can't phase out right away. Default tracking for GA is super simple in GTM.

Comment: Hey @Boosted_d16 - sorry for the late reply but yeah we removed the GA snippet and added in GTM. Along with this we added in events on the website for e-commerce tracking (this has to be done by developers). For basic GA, the GTM tag works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the info, really useful.